# Skyrim Personal Chest Sorting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have purchased the home in Whiterun and been storing a bunch of items in my chest in that home.  I noticed that that chest only has one category where is shows everything instead of like my regular inventory which has weapons, appeal, food, books, etc...  My question is if there is a way to get that type of categories with a personal chest or if a different chest that I can use for storage has this feature?  It is just annoying that if I want to start doing alchemy with everything I have collected, I have to go through every single item and see if it is an ingredient for alchemy instead of going to the ingredient category and easily getting each one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in the base game.

Your only real option is to self-sort. Luckily, your house in Whiterun has multiple chests (when fully upgraded), including a chest near the alchemy station, so at the very least you can store certain items in certain chests to keep things straight and ordered.

Comment: Yea, was thinking about this too.  I guess this will work few well even though it is not ideal.  Thanks

Comment: actually, there is a small satchel on the alchemy table in Whiterun .

Answer (score 5):

There is a mod for Skyrim that does this (assuming you are playing on PC).  To get it working, you will need both the [Skyrim Script Extender](https://skse.silverlock.org/)  and the [**Container Categorization**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1227) mod that uses it.

To use them, put the Script Extender in the same directory as Skyrim.  Put the mod files in your Skyrim directory per the directions in the file. Then run Skyrim using the Script Extender executable rather than the Skyrim launcher.

If you are hesitant about running executables from the Internet (and you should be) google "fallout script extender" or "oblivion script extender" to see for yourself what people have said about that team of programmers over the years.

Comment: I'm using this. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that containers do not sort their items by type/category the way your personal inventory or merchants' inventories are sorted.  You'll likely have to wait for a mod to implement this functionality.

I will say I've found it much more convenient to store alchemy ingredients in the chest atop the bookshelf next to the alchemy table in your Whiterun house.

Comment: Same here. Worth noting: There's an ingredient satchel on the alchemist's table in the house in Whiterun. I don't use the satchel, as I heard there was a bug that sometimes the alchemist's table disappears. The satchel does start with some ingredients - mine had a human heart. Where on earth did the Jarl's steward find a human heart?

Answer (score 2):

There are no chests with categories like your own inventory.

Of course, you could use multiple chests/containers to store different types of items. For example, store apparel/armor in the wardrobe, alchemy ingredients in the satchel near the alchemist table, etc. It even feels 'right' in a role-playing sense. ;)