# Sorting (order) items in the chest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I understand that, at least in the base game, you cannot have [catagorisation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38472/skyrim-personal-chest-sorting) on your chest inventory.
But, conceding to that, is there anyway to even force sorting?

Like, I have a chest full of armour, and whilst most of the items are ordered alphabetically, some of the items appear in random places, making it a pain in the butt to find specific things.

I was wondering if it could be done without mods (because, of course, mods can do *anything*). Something like `open console`, `click chest`, `enter 'orderChest'` or something.

Because the game can sort, and it usually does, I just have some rogue items that disobey and maybe getting (forcing) the game to do it again may fix it

Answer (score 6):

[SkyUI](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/3863) has many sorting options for your inventory, containers, the magic menu and more. It can even sort items by their price/weight ratio for the discerning thief. If you happen to be playing Skyrim on a console, then accept my sincerest sympathy - there is no way to sort items without mods.

Comment: 1up for useful mod, but I was looking for a non-mod answer

Comment: I believe the sorting functions are implemented in the Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE), so i doubt it is possible without **some** degree of modding. Considering you are talking about console commands, you must be playing on PC, and in that case I cannot recommend SkyUI highly enough - you will not believe you were actually able to play without it once you try it.

Comment: SkyUI is the only mod I will not play without.